# Python read file and assign split list data to dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to read lines from a file and create an `OrderedDict` from split line data from a file but it seems that I'm only able to get the **last** line to output to my dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

city_file = open('US.txt', 'r')

cities = OrderedDict()
states = OrderedDict()

for row in city_file:
    city_data = row.split('\t')

    print(city_data)  # prints each list row of the file just fine

    state = city_data[3].strip()

    states[state] = {
        'name': state,
        'code': city_data[4].strip(),
    }

    cities[city_data[5]] = {
        'name': city_data[5].strip(),
        'state': list(states.keys()).index(state) + 1,
        'zip_code': city_data[1].strip(),
        'latitude': city_data[9].strip(),
        'longitude': city_data[10].strip()
    }
```

I am unable to get a dictionary of each unique state or city with their corresponding column data from the text file.

It seems the reference to the `city_data` list is lost when I assign it to the dictionary `states`. Why is that?

**Each row in the file looks something like this:**

```
US  99788   Chalkyitsik Alaska  AK  Yukon-Koyukuk (CA)  290         65.2264 -151.0251
US  36003   Autaugaville    Alabama AL  Autauga 001         32.4625 -86.7149
```

**Edit: Clarification** In my end result I'm trying to get a dictionary of states with each unique state name as the key (so the state dict should have 50 states), the cities dict should have every city name for each key. But when I perform a len(cities) the length is 1 with only the last one being stored in the dict.

Comment: what does states look like when you leave the loop? (print states) Running your code (with using split() instead of split('\t')) I got "OrderedDict([('AK', {'country': 'Chalkyitsik', 'name': 'AK'}), ('AL', {'country': 'Autaugaville', 'name': 'AL'})])"

Comment: The reference to `city_data` is lost because you don't store it anywhere. Notice that multiple entries for a given state overwrite earlier entries. Is that intended? You don't even try to track eac hunique city, so its not surprising that it doesn't have any data.

Comment: Sorry I want to have a list of say 50 states saved in a dictionary and all cities with their city name as the dictionary key

it seems the states dictionary doesn't save anything besides the last state:
OrderedDict([('Wyoming', {'name': 'Wyoming', 'code': 'WY'})])

Comment: @MasterOdin - its pretty obvious what's in `states` - dicts of the last `city_data` encountered for each state.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure this is all of your code?

Comment: city_data is temporal variable here. you assign it a new value in each iteration. only the last iteration values will be stored if you write this code in interactive python shell.

Comment: BTW: why are you storing the `key` values (`state` and `city_data[5]`) in the dicts too - that information is implicit in the keys of the OrderedDicts.

Comment: I was storing the keys so that states and cities aren't duplicated since this dataset is for every county in the US. So using states and cities I won't get any duplication

Comment: @marmeladze  Shouldn't the city dict get stored at least until the next loop iteration so that I should have 50 state keys in my states dictionary?

Comment: This isn't going to do anything useful: `'state': list(states.keys()).index(state) + 1,`. You seem to be wanting an index for the `dict` but `dict` keys reorder every time you add something to them. Just use the name of the state to index it.

Comment: @bill you are just printing city data - and it is splitting each row with tab and prints them out normally.

for cities dictionary everthing is also ok - just add `print [keys for keys in  cities.keys()]` and it will spit out keys of your cities dict

Comment: Guys... I feel like an idiot. It was because I was pasting it in the iPython editor and forgot to do %cpaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment wanting `OrderedDict([('Wyoming', {'name': 'Wyoming', 'code': 'WY'})])`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

city_file = open('US.txt', 'r')
states = OrderedDict()
cities = OrderedDict()
for row in city_file:
    data = [e.strip() for e in row.split('  ')]
    states[data[3]] = {
        'name': data[3],
        'code': data[4]
        }
    cities[data[5]] = {
        'name': data[5],
        'state': data[3],
        'zip_code': data[1],
        'latitude': data[8],
        'longitude': data[9]
    }
```

Output:

```
>>> states
OrderedDict([('AK', {'code': 'Yukon-Koyukuk (CA)', 'name': 'AK'}), ('', {'code': 'Alabama AL', 'name': ''})])
>>> cities
OrderedDict([('290', {'latitude': '', 'state': 'AK', 'name': '290', 'longitude': '65.2264 -151.0251', 'zip_code': '99788'}), ('Autauga 001', {'latitude': '', 'state': '', 'name': 'Autauga 001', 'longitude': '32.4625 -86.7149', 'zip_code': '36003'})])
```

Comment: Then he needs to clarify.